# how to update multiple columns depending on same set of conditions?

Tags: mysql

```
    update employee as e,employee_salary as es
    set e.annualincome=
    case e.currentgrade
    when 1 then e.annualincome+e.annualincome*0.10
    when 2 then e.annualincome+e.annualincome*0.15
    end,
    es.income=
    case e.currentgrade
    when 1 then es.income+es.income*0.10
    when 2 then es.income+es.income*0.15
    end
    where e.employeeid=es.employeeid and salarydate >'2011-09-01%';
```

I'm updating two columns of two different tables based on same condition how can I do this with a single case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think your current solution is deficient in some way but (if the increase is calculable from the grade) one solution would be to use `currentgrade` in the formulae, something like:

```
update employee as e, employee_salary as es
    set e.annualincome = e.annualincome * (1.05 + e.currentgrade * 0.05),
    set es.income      = es.income      * (1.05 + e.currentgrade * 0.05)
where e.employeeid = es.employeeid
  and e.currentgrade in (1,2)
  and salarydate > '2011-09-01%';
```

But, honestly, I'd stick with what you have. The intent is clear and could be made even clearer with a little bit of indentation management :-)

Since you have indicated that the increase is *not* calculable from the grade, an alternative is to do it as two stages under the control of a transaction, which is even clearer:

```
update employee as e, employee_salary as es
    set e.annualincome = e.annualincome * 1.10,
    set es.income      = es.income      * 1.10
where e.employeeid = es.employeeid
  and e.currentgrade = 1
  and salarydate >'2011-09-01%';

update employee as e, employee_salary as es
    set e.annualincome = e.annualincome * 1.15,
    set es.income      = es.income      * 1.15
where e.employeeid = es.employeeid
  and e.currentgrade = 2
  and salarydate >'2011-09-01%';
```

That's also likely to run a lot faster if you have an index on `currentgrade` that gets used. Per-row functions (including `case`) applied to every are not known for their scalability. It's usually better to reduce the row count as early as possible.

Comment: currentgrade is no way related with the percentage increase.But depending on currentgrade we'll update the income and annualincome with specified percentage.

Comment: @pavi: then look to the transactional solution at the end. This is (IMNSHO) much more explicit than both the (now erroneous) "increase-tied-to-grade" solution and the convoluted expressions in the original question.

Comment: I should perform the update in single query coz it'll increase the overhead on server

Comment: @pavi, you might want to _measure_ the performance on the server. I think you'll be surprised. The number of queries is not usually the killer, it's more often the complexity of those queries.

Comment: Thank you verymuch.I didn't know this.So you think the second query would be efficient than the one i wrote?

Comment: It _could_ be, yes (that's why you should always measure things on production-like data). With your query, it's likely that the execution engine will simply grab every row and make a per-row decision based on its contents. With a transactioned dual-update, no decisions need to be made for each row - once you have the set of rows satisfying the currentgrade where clause, you just do the multiplication. You also process no extra rows but just do it in two chunks. But as with all optimisations: _measure, don't guess!_